# Asp.net if session value = 'something' change class in css

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, session

I have to give a display:none to a class called "plus" whenever the variable boolean = true in my session.

I'm working with asp.net. In my code behind I can't get my classes. In javascript I can't get my session.

Does anyone has a possible solution (without having to use runat=server" and call it on the behind code with the ID?

Comment: are you using asp.net web forms or mvc?

Comment: I'm using web forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code something like below. Basically injecting Javascript code based on condition in the server side:

```
if ((bool)Session[""])
        {
            var script = "jQuery('.plus').hide();";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "hideplus", script, true);
        }
```